# MySQL joining with grouping did not join perfectly

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have three table and want to join them but the join returns a single row multiple time when using group by parent id from contact table.

`contact` table-

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Murad |
| 2 | Tajharul |

`phone` table-

| id | contact_id | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 017 |
| 2 | 2 | 014 |
| 3 | 2 | 015 |

`email` table-

| id | contact_id | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | mur@test.com |
| 2 | 1 | has@test.com |
| 3 | 1 | tan@test.com |
| 4 | 2 | taj@test.com |
| 5 | 2 | har@test.com |

Desired Output-

| id | Name | Phone | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Murad | 017 | mur@test.com,has@test.com,tan@test.com |
| 2 | Tajharul | 014,015 | taj@test.com,har@test.com |

Here is what I have tried so far-

```
SELECT contact.name , GROUP_CONCAT(phone.phone) phone, GROUP_CONCAT(email.email) email
FROM 
    contact 
    JOIN phone ON contact.id = phone.contact_id
    JOIN email ON contact.id = email.contact_id
GROUP BY contact.id
```

MySQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded29f/1

Comment: Use `distinct`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded29f/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using subquery and Distinct in Group concat:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T1.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email.email) email
FROM 
    (SELECT contact.id, contact.name , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT phone.phone) phone
    FROM 
        contact 
        JOIN phone ON contact.id = phone.contact_id
  GROUP BY contact.id) T1
JOIN email ON T1.id = email.contact_id
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Comment: Second contact has same email twice.. [New link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded29f/7)

Comment: I have updated the solution, check now

Comment: Ok, let me check

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT in group_concat

```
SELECT contact.name , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT phone.phone) phone, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email.email) email
FROM 
    contact 
    JOIN phone ON contact.id = phone.contact_id
    JOIN email ON contact.id = email.contact_id
GROUP BY contact.id
```

Comment: Second contact has same email twice.. [New Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ded29f/7)

Comment: If you don't want distinct on emails remove DISTINCT